# Error When using "WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone" in Swift 3

Tags: swift, ios10

Trying to add `WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone` to `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback` for a `WKWebview`. But I can't get it to work.

**Error**

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'WKaudiovisualMediaTypeNone'"

**in this context**

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone; // Error getting here
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: webConfiguration) 
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no option with `.None`. If you don't want to pass anything you can go for below code:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    webConfiguration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
}
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: webConfiguration)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did see that this only works in iOS10, is there a way to make this work in version before iOS10?

Comment: I got an error on "mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all" its says "Type 'WKAudiovisualMediaTypes' has no member 'all' "

Comment: @user2673664 `Swift` version?

Comment: Apple Swift version 3.0.1

Comment: I am on the same version. It's not giving me any error.

Comment: I did change the .all to [] and it worked. Thanks for all the help :D

Answer (score 3):

```
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
```

**[Apple Doc:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkaudiovisualmediatypes)**

> To indicate that no user gestures are required to play media, use an empty set of audio/visual media types, indicated by the empty array literal, [].
>
> For example, `let myAudiovisualMediaType: WKAudiovisualMediaTypes = []`.